How are 3 Principle Sections possible in a crystal even when there is only one optical axis and all must contain it?
While studying polarization in calcite crystals, I came across that there are 3 possible principle sections in the rhombohedral crystal. But the conditions are that each section must be perpendicular to a pair of opposite faces of the crystal while also containing the optical axis. How is this possible because there is only one plane that has both the conditions satisfied. All other planes would have to be at an angle to the optical axis.
